# In Datadog, is there a JavaScript library that allows you to get existing metric data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datadog, telemetry

For example, suppose I have a Node library that I could use something like:

```
var datadog = require('some datadog library for JS');
var currentValue = datadog.getMetric('my.existing.metric');
console.log(currentValue);
//currentValue --> 72

var currentMetrics = datadog.getAllMetrics();
console.log(currentMetrics);
// currentMetrics --> ['my.existing.metric','my.existing.metric.1','my.existing.metric.2']

var currentMonitors = data.getAllMonitors();
console.log(currentMonitors);
// currentMonitors --> [{name:'my.monitor.1', status:'GOOD'},{name:'my.monitor.1', status:'BAD'}]
```

The few I've looked at all seem to be good for posting new data to Datadog, however, are there any that can pull data from Datadog? Does anything like this exist? I like the [Datadog API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/) but it seems as though that is only in Curl, Python, and Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

There is [dogapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dogapi) which wraps the entire Datadog API and should be able to do the above use case, probably using a mix of [metric.query](https://brettlangdon.github.io/node-dogapi/#metric-query), [infrastructure.search](https://brettlangdon.github.io/node-dogapi/#infrastructure-search), [search.query](https://brettlangdon.github.io/node-dogapi/#search-query) and [monitor.getAll](https://brettlangdon.github.io/node-dogapi/#monitor-getAll).

For example, to get the list of monitors, it would look something like this:

```js
const dogapi = require('dogapi')

dogapi.initialize({
  api_key: 'your_api_key',
  app_key: 'your_app_key'
})

dogapi.monitor.getAll((err, res) => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Please keep in mind that I didn't test the above code.

If you need something that is not in the library, it should also be fairly easy to wrap the API directly since it's a simple HTTP endpoint.

I hope this helps!